# iCarousel scrolling is not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

I am working on the icarousel of type “iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2”.I am using Label which displays the names in that.For that I am using the following method

```
func carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation(carousel: iCarousel) {

         print(carousel.currentItemIndex)
        namesLabel.text = self.godsNamesArray.objectAtIndex(carousel.currentItemIndex) as? String

  }
```

The problem I am facing in this method is

```
   In that I am printing the “carousel.currentItemIndex”.
For the first time it is printing the currentItemIndex is”0”
For the second time it is printing the currentItemIndex is ”-1”
That’s why the app is getting crash with the following error
```

> -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.What is the mistake I am doing here.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: It seems that you have not set your carousel to wrap around. In this case it seems you are getting a current item index of -1, presumably as the carousel bounces off the end. You may get better results with the delegat method `carouselCurentItemIndexDidChange` and you should also check the value of the index before accessing the array to ensure it is valid.

Comment: Thank you so much.It is working fine now.